# How to add two values from two different functions and display it in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two Javascript functions that calculates a value at the end and displays that in HTML. I would like to add two values at the end of each function together and display it in HTML just like I did the other two values of each functions which is in the  tag.

I've tried returning the values and still was not able to solve this.

```js
function calcA1() {
  var Aa1 = document.getElementById('Aa1');
  var Ab1 = document.getElementById('Ab1');
  var Ac1 = document.getElementById('Ac1');
  var Aa1Val = Aa1.options[Aa1.selectedIndex].value;
  var Ab1Val = Ab1.options[Ab1.selectedIndex].value;
  var Ac1Val = Ac1.options[Ac1.selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById("A1").innerHTML = parseInt(Aa1Val) + parseInt(Ab1Val) + parseInt(Ac1Val);
}

function calcA2() {
  var Aa2 = document.getElementById('Aa2');
  var Ab2 = document.getElementById('Ab2');
  var Ac2 = document.getElementById('Ac2');
  var Ad2 = document.getElementById('Ad2');
  var Aa2Val = Aa2.options[Aa2.selectedIndex].value;
  var Ab2Val = Ab2.options[Ab2.selectedIndex].value;
  var Ac2Val = Ac2.options[Ac2.selectedIndex].value;
  var Ad2Val = Ad2.options[Ad2.selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById("A2").innerHTML = parseInt(Aa2Val) + parseInt(Ab2Val) + parseInt(Ac2Val) + parseInt(Ad2Val);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="blueHead">
    <th>A. Governing Principles, Functional Pride and Quality Assurance</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="blueHead">
    <td><b>A.1  Successful maintenance functions are built upon a foundation of governing principles and concepts proven over the years in many industries.</b></td>
    <td><b>Value</b></td>
    <td><b>Awarded</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a) The maintenance strategic plan is documented and aligned with the plant’s strategic business plan.</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcA1();" id="Aa1">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b) Maintenance Mission Statement is consistent with best practice philosophy, and is posted where all plant personnel can view the statement. </td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcA1();" id="Ab1">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>c) The Maintenance Mission Statement is known and understood by all maintenance personnel.</td>
    <td align="center">2</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcA1();" id="Ac1">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="subtotal">Sub Total</td>
    <td align="center"><b>4</b></td>
    <td align="center"><b><div id="A1"></div></b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="blueHead">
    <td><b>A.2 The concept of operating proprietorship is basic to facility philosophy. All organizational units share responsibility for the preservation of all assets (processes, equipment, and facilities). A Maintenance/Production Partnership is evident. Mutual understanding and cooperation is excellent. Important procedures, such as the work order system, are followed with uniformity.</b></td>
    <th><b>Value</b></th>
    <th><b>Awarded</b></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a) A production operator-training plan is written and functioning. </td>
    <td align="center">2</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcA2();" id="Aa2">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b) Portion of PPM program completed by Production is tracked; compliance is reported at least monthly. </td>
    <td align="center">2</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcA2();" id="Ab2">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c) Production operators perform a portion of PM/PdM program. </td>
    <td align="center">2</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcA2();" id="Ac2">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d) Production operators effectively perform routine setups, changeovers and equipment adjustments. </td>
    <td align="center">2</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcA2();" id="Ad2">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="subtotal">Sub Total</td>
    <td align="center"><b>8</b></td>
    <td align="center"><b><div id="A2"></div></b></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: not clear at all !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing right now is the functions actually write the value to the DOM.  You could change the functions to return a number, and then either write the value to the DOM, or whatever else you need to do.

```
function display(elementid, value) {
    document.getElementById(elementid).innerHTML = value;
}

function calcA1() {
    var Aa1 = document.getElementById('Aa1');
    var Ab1 = document.getElementById('Ab1');
    var Ac1 = document.getElementById('Ac1');

    var Aa1Val = Aa1.options[Aa1.selectedIndex].value;
    var Ab1Val = Ab1.options[Ab1.selectedIndex].value;
    var Ac1Val = Ac1.options[Ac1.selectedIndex].value;

    return parseInt(Aa1Val) + parseInt(Ab1Val) + parseInt(Ac1Val);
}

function calcA2() {
    var Aa2 = document.getElementById('Aa2');
    var Ab2 = document.getElementById('Ab2');
    var Ac2 = document.getElementById('Ac2');
    var Ad2 = document.getElementById('Ad2');

    var Aa2Val = Aa2.options[Aa2.selectedIndex].value;
    var Ab2Val = Ab2.options[Ab2.selectedIndex].value;
    var Ac2Val = Ac2.options[Ac2.selectedIndex].value;
    var Ad2Val = Ad2.options[Ad2.selectedIndex].value;

    return parseInt(Aa2Val) + parseInt(Ab2Val) + parseInt(Ac2Val) + parseInt(Ad2Val);
}

function calcA3() {
    return calcA1() + calcA2();
}
```

Then you just need a small change to handle the events:

```
<td align="center">
  <select class="select" onChange="a1ChangeHandler()" id="Aa1">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

so your change handler would look like this:

```
function a1ChangeHandler() {
  display("A1", calcA1());
  display("A3", calcA3());
}
```

Protip: [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think you should rework your code a bit - if you put a bit more thought into the selectors, then you could solve with a much shorter code.

```js
function calcA1R() {
  var Aa1 = document.getElementById('Aa1');
  var Ab1 = document.getElementById('Ab1');
  var Ac1 = document.getElementById('Ac1');

  var Aa1Val = Aa1.options[Aa1.selectedIndex].value;
  var Ab1Val = Ab1.options[Ab1.selectedIndex].value;
  var Ac1Val = Ac1.options[Ac1.selectedIndex].value;

  // returning the sum of the values
  return [parseInt(Aa1Val), parseInt(Ab1Val), parseInt(Ac1Val)].reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0)
}

function calcA1() {
  // anything changes displaySum() runs
  displaySum()
  document.getElementById("A1").innerHTML = calcA1R();
}

function calcA2R() {
  var Aa2 = document.getElementById('Aa2');
  var Ab2 = document.getElementById('Ab2');
  var Ac2 = document.getElementById('Ac2');
  var Ad2 = document.getElementById('Ad2');

  var Aa2Val = Aa2.options[Aa2.selectedIndex].value;
  var Ab2Val = Ab2.options[Ab2.selectedIndex].value;
  var Ac2Val = Ac2.options[Ac2.selectedIndex].value;
  var Ad2Val = Ad2.options[Ad2.selectedIndex].value;

  // returning the sum of the values
  return [parseInt(Aa2Val), parseInt(Ab2Val), parseInt(Ac2Val), parseInt(Ad2Val)].reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0)
}

function calcA2() {
  // anything changes displaySum() runs
  displaySum()
  document.getElementById("A2").innerHTML = calcA2R()
}

function displaySum() {
  document.getElementById('total').textContent = calcSum()
}

function calcSum() {
  return calcA1R() + calcA2R()
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="blueHead">
    <th>A. Governing Principles, Functional Pride and Quality Assurance</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="blueHead">
    <td><b>A.1  Successful maintenance functions are built upon a foundation of governing principles and concepts proven over the years in many industries.</b></td>
    <td><b>Value</b></td>
    <td><b>Awarded</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a) The maintenance strategic plan is documented and aligned with the plant’s strategic business plan.</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcA1();" id="Aa1">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b) Maintenance Mission Statement is consistent with best practice philosophy, and is posted where all plant personnel can view the statement. </td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcA1();" id="Ab1">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>c) The Maintenance Mission Statement is known and understood by all maintenance personnel.</td>
    <td align="center">2</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcA1();" id="Ac1">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="subtotal">Sub Total</td>
    <td align="center"><b>4</b></td>
    <td align="center"><b><div id="A1"></div></b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="blueHead">
    <td><b>A.2 The concept of operating proprietorship is basic to facility philosophy. All organizational units share responsibility for the preservation of all assets (processes, equipment, and facilities). A Maintenance/Production Partnership is evident. Mutual understanding and cooperation is excellent. Important procedures, such as the work order system, are followed with uniformity.</b></td>
    <th><b>Value</b></th>
    <th><b>Awarded</b></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a) A production operator-training plan is written and functioning. </td>
    <td align="center">2</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcA2();" id="Aa2">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b) Portion of PPM program completed by Production is tracked; compliance is reported at least monthly. </td>
    <td align="center">2</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcA2();" id="Ab2">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c) Production operators perform a portion of PM/PdM program. </td>
    <td align="center">2</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcA2();" id="Ac2">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d) Production operators effectively perform routine setups, changeovers and equipment adjustments. </td>
    <td align="center">2</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcA2();" id="Ad2">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="subtotal">Sub Total</td>
    <td align="center"><b>8</b></td>
    <td align="center"><b><div id="A2"></div></b></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div>TOTAL: <span id="total"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just needed a little tweaking in your JS code. Just replace your script with this one.

```
function calcA1() {
var Aa1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('Aa1').value);
var Ab1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('Ab1').value);
var Ac1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('Ac1').value);

document.getElementById("A1").innerHTML = Aa1 + Ab1 + Ac1;
}

function calcA2() {
var Aa2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('Aa2').value);
var Ab2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('Ab2').value);
var Ac2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('Ac2').value);
var Ad2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('Ad2').value);

document.getElementById("A2").innerHTML = Aa2 + Ab2 + Ac2 + Ad2;
}
```